# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'r.when_added' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, inner-join

What seems to be problem here?

***Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'r.when_added' in 'on clause'***

```
 SELECT r.coupon_id, c.who_added, c.coupon_name, r.when_added,
           (select count(*) 
            FROM redeemed_coupons r2 JOIN
                 coupon c2
                 ON r2.coupon_id = c2.coupon_id AND
                    c2.who_added = 1 AND
                    r2.when_added BETWEEN 1602827745 AND 1613084678 AND
                    r2.when_added = r.when_added
          )
    FROM redeemed_coupons r JOIN
         coupon c
         ON r.coupon_id = c.coupon_id AND
            c.who_added = 1 AND
            r.when_added BETWEEN 1602827745 AND 1613084678
    ORDER BY r.when_added ;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try putting that condition in a `WHERE` clause . . . `WHERE r2.when_added = r.when_added`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your query, I doubt that you actually need a `join` in the subquery. Doesn't this do what you want?

```
SELECT r.coupon_id, c.who_added, c.coupon_name, r.when_added,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM redeemed_coupons r2 
        WHERE r2.coupon_id = c.coupon_id AND r2.when_added = r.when_added
    ) cnt
FROM redeemed_coupons r 
INNER JOIN coupon c ON c.coupon_id = r.coupon_id  
WHERE r.when_added BETWEEN 1602827745 AND 1613084678 AND c.who_added = 1
ORDER BY r.when_added ;
```

Apart from the changes in the suqbuery, I also re-organized a little the conditions in the outer query; this does not change the result, but I find it more readable to only put the correlation conditions in the `ON` clause, and other conditions in the `WHERE` clause.

You could also express this with a window `count()`, if you are running MySQL 8.0:

```
SELECT r.coupon_id, c.who_added, c.coupon_name, r.when_added,
    COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY r.coupon_id, r.when_added) cnt
FROM redeemed_coupons r 
INNER JOIN coupon c
    ON  r.coupon_id = c.coupon_id 
    AND c.who_added = 1 
    AND r.when_added BETWEEN 1602827745 AND 1613084678
ORDER BY r.when_added ;
```